# What does "dar / tomar por saco" really mean, and where does it come from?

Tags: modismos, significado

As far as I know, "**tomar por saco**" is a synonym for "[tomar por culo](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=culo#DIbHGip)" which literally means (pardon my French here) "to be fucked in the ass".
Both expressions are normally used to tell the listener to go away, to leave us alone -- similar to the expression "fuck off" in English (which also shares the use of "fuck").
I've also seen it used in the form "**dar por saco**" (as in "vengo a darte por saco un rato") meaning "to bother someone" and it is also interchangeable with "dar por culo".

So it'd seem like "saco" (literally: bag, sac) is just being used as slang for ass.
However, looking at the dictionary "[saco](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=WwqIKzJ)" does not mean ass, nor does it seem to be a slang for it, out of this single saying.

So does it really mean what I thought? And if so, how did it came to mean that?

Comment: I can't answer your main question. But I would say "por saco" is an eufemism of "por culo" on all those expressions, just to avoid "culo" (which sounds offensive). I won't speculate about similarities between an ass and a big bag.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe *dar por saco* is older than *dar por culo*. I found *dar por saco* in a poem written in 1627 called *Poema del asalto y conquista de Antequera*

Comment: This may be of some interest to you: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dar-tomar-por-saco-culo.371407/. They say the full (archaic) form of the expression is "Dar por donde se rompe el saco". You could compare it to the English expression "Don't let it hit ya where the good Lord split ya".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [a forum post on WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/dar-tomar-por-saco-culo.371407/), the original form may have been:

> Dar donde se rompe el saco.

## Theory number one

The "rip in the bag" would correspond to one's buttcrack.

Here's [another source](https://ar.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070324043417AAjJewo) claiming the same origin for it:

> En su origen era "que te den por donde se rompe el saco" (el "saco" era el calzón que se utilizaba antiguamente, en lugar de pantalones).

This one says that a *"saco"* was a type of pants.
And RAE does cite something similar as the meanings 4-6 of *"[saco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WwqIKzJ)"*:

> 4. m. Vestidura tosca y áspera de paño burdo o sayal.
> 5. m. Especie de gabán grande y, en general, vestidura holgada que no se ajusta al cuerpo.
> 6. m. Vestido corto que usaban los antiguos romanos, excepto los varones consulares, en tiempo de guerra.

So it has had a meaning as different clothes.

## Theory number two

It seems that the equivalent expression in German is

> Fick dich ins Knie!

Multiple sources (eg. [this](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~Fick%20dich%20ins%20Knie%21&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)) would quote 'Knie' here not to mean 'knee' but be a shortened version of 'Kniefiez', meaning an avaricious person. If the expression was borrowed, it could have been translated as saco as per the expression 'La avaricia rompe el saco.' That would explain the rather weird use of 'por donde' as combining the German 'ins' matching 'por' in this context and 'donde' from the Spanish expression.

The timeframes would make some sense with the German expression being born in the early 1940s in its long form and the first occurrence of the Spanish one in the CREA in the 1990s. Google NGram quotes one case in the year 1920 (statistical noise?) and a steady uptake from the 1960s onwards.

This is to be taken with a large pinch of salt: forum posts can't be called a credible source, and Spanish is not my first, second, third, fourth or even fifth language.

Comment: Note that _se rompe el saco_ also refers to the mother-to-be's water breaking.

Comment: Yes, I did notice it.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo contigo. Es posible que no sea la origen verdadera, pero no pienso que el CORDE y CREA sean tampoco las mejores fuentes en este caso. Tienen sólo algunas cuarenta resultados para "dar/tomar por culo/saco" y si comprendo bien, no son expresiónes típicamente encontradas en libros.

Comment: @mdewey Which could maybe make saco refer to female genitalia?

Comment: My comment was intended to be helpful if someone tried searching (perhaps on Google N-gram) for the phrase.

Comment: Still no luck. Regarding saco meaning female genitalia: seems improbable, as I can name three languages off the top of my head (Finish, French and well Spanish) with something akin to 'por culo' but not really anything with that meaning. 'Por saco' would also seem to be a Spanish-only expression with even close relatives not having anything equivalent.

Comment: @walen So no, I can't find better sources. I am starting to believe the better sourced theory b myself, though.

Comment: And if we can't get a better source, we can always ask RAE via Twitter...

Comment: ...or judging by what is happening on the Tertulia side of things, ask them in person. Or even plead audience on grounds of this exceptional dillema.

Answer (score 1):

Me temo que solo puedo contestar a tu pregunta ¿Qué significa?

Esta expresión "A tomar por saco" significa "**Vete y déjame**", "Vete lejos y déjame tranquilo", "Vete y no molestes", "Vete lejos"

> La expresión de esta semana "mandar (a alguien) a tomar por saco" es
>   una expresión popular que se utiliza para decirle a una persona que se
>   encuentra en un sitio en el que molesta o que su presencia molesta a
>   otras personas que están en el mismo sitio y quieren que ésta se vaya.
>   Esta definición de esta expresión es similar a la expresión "mandar/ir
>   a freír espárragos". También se usa para decir que se envía a una
>   persona a un lugar muy lejano, similar a la expresión "irse al quinto
>   pino".[fuente](https://www.newsinslowspanish.com/catalog/spanish-expressions-proverbs/203/Mandar-a-tomar-por-saco)

El sinónimos más soez de esta expresión es, como indicas "vete a tomar por culo" sin embargo, no significa "being fucked in the ass". El significado es el mismo que el anterior: "Vete y déjame".

Algunos usos de esta expresión son:

1. Una persona te está molestando y quieres que deje de hacerlo. Podrías pedirle formalmente "Deja de molestarme" pero, en cambio, le dices "vete a tomar por saco" para que vaya a otra parte.
2. En una conversación alguien dice algo exagerado, que parece imposible. Ante ello le responder "vete a tomar por saco" en el sentido de "no te lo crees ni tu".

> Se manda a alguien a tomar por saco cuando queremos faltarle al
>   respeto, cuando queremos que desaparezca o cuando queremos mostrarle
>   nuestro enfado, indignación, profunda decepción, etc.  Es como mandar
>   a la mierda o al carajo.
>
> Ejemplos:
>
> - Que se vayan a tomar por saco todos los que critican a mi familia.
> - Cuando la policía paró el coche del viejo borracho, éste se bajó y los mandó a tomar por saco.[Fuente](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/33837-a-tomar-por-saco)

Sigo buscando cómo esta expresión ha derivado así.

Comment: ¿Pero de dónde viene usar _saco_?